# How to include 'dialog' command into Linux kickstart?

Tags: linux, installation, dialog

I am trying to use Linux command 'dialog'(1) (/usr/bin/dialog) in my kickstart script (ks.cfg).

However the initial running system does not have it during installation.

It seems even many of the running systems don't have dialog command either.

But I have a DVD with ks.cfg which uses dialog and installs well.

Can someone please figure out how to make it available during installation?

I checked initrd of the DVD I mentioned above which has dialog included; it is not there.

And please, if someone is going to move this question to server fault, can you leave it here for a few days? I wish more people can see this question for I found kickstart related questions don't get answers soon.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps what looks like `dialog` is actually [`whiptail`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newt_(programming_library))? I seem to have a vague memory of RedHat preferring `whiptail` for some reason.

Comment: @sarnold Thanks, I checked out whiptail on a few running systems that don't have dialog. I found it. This is very valuable information!! However, my script is not able to access whiptail neither :( And I still dont have idea on how to add my favorite programs into install initial image.